# load data by ajax disappeared when validation return error

Tags: php, yii

I had form content first name, last name .....etc. And tow drowpdownlist  countries and cities, I loaded cities when Country drowpdownlist changed by ajax, and everything is cool.
My problems:

1- when clicked submit and had error in validation, city value will replaced with empty value 
How to fix it?

2- How  to use $form->  with it I mean city drowpdownlist   .

- Form work if no error in validation
  [image: Wrok]
- Form after clicked on submit and return error in validation like username is empty ..etc
  [image: Error]

View:

```
        <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'البلد'); ?>
    <?php

    /*
     echo chtml::activeDropDownList($model,'country',$model->getcountry(),array('prompt'=>'اختر بلدك ')   , 
    array(
'ajax' => array(
'type'=>'POST', //request type
'url'=>CController::createUrl('current/dynamiccities'), //url to call.
//Style: CController::createUrl('currentController/methodToCall')
'update'=>'#city', //selector to update
//'data'=>'js:javascript statement' 
//leave out the data key to pass all form values through
))

    ); 

    */
    echo CHtml::activedropDownList($model,'country',$model->getcountry(),

    array(
    'prompt'=>'اختر البلد أو المنطقة ',
'ajax' => array(
'type'=>'POST', //request type
'url'=>CController::createUrl('register/dynamiccities'), //url to call.
//Style: CController::createUrl('currentController/methodToCall')
'update'=>'#city', //selector to update
//'data'=>'js:javascript statement' 
//leave out the data key to pass all form values through
))
    );

   ///

    ////

    ?>


        <?php echo $form->error($model,'country'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'المدينة'); ?>
        <?php 

echo CHtml::dropDownList('city','', array());

 ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'city'); ?>
    </div>
```

controller for cities load:

```
public function actionDynamiccities() /// Call Ajax
{
    $country=intval($_POST['Users']['country']);

    $data=Cities::model()->findAll('country_id=:country_id', 
                  array(':country_id'=>$country));
    $data=CHtml::listData($data,'id','city_name_e');
     echo CHtml::tag('option',
                array('value'=>''),CHtml::encode('Select Your City '),true);

    foreach($data as $value=>$name)
    {
        echo CHtml::tag('option',
                   array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name),true);
    };
}
```

Comment: Don't say worst Code , just fix or tell me my wrong .. this platform for shearing knowledge ;) Not just for say " worst code i've ever seen "

Comment: i just cant hold myself when i saw this :)

Comment: but i cant find nothing in that code. you can use debugger to step-by-step passing through your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at this line

> echo CHtml::dropDownList('city','', array());

It is obvious that the list is empty, and it would also be empty if you wanted to edit the content later.

I would suggest using something like

> echo CHtml::dropDownList('city', $model->city, empty($model->country) ? array() : CHtml::listData(Cities::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('country_id' => $model->country)),'id','city_name_e'));

Here i don't know if you should use `$model->country` or `$model->country_id`, depends on your model.

Comment: Thank you jborch , i guess your answer is so logical , but i had problem ? How to use it with  dropDownList ??! 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try `echo CHtml::dropDownList('city, $model->city, empty($model->country) ? array() : Cities::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('country_id' => $model->country)));`?

Comment: after submit i had this error 
Object of class Cities could not be converted to string 
http://im30.gulfup.com/DEfI1.png

Comment: I tried it but not returned any thing , your code in comment seem better for me can you edit it to work with " dropDownList " .